# how to use i18next 3.4.1 in an amd (require js) project

Tags: requirejs, amd, i18next

in first version of i18next there was a file called `i18next.amd.withJQuery`
but in latest version this support is not there and moreover lot has changed in latest version.
How do we access i18next object from different define modules ?

Answer (score 0):

`i18next` is currently a UMD package. `i18next` does not require `jQuery` now. Use `i18next.js`